# Saving phone number and email to contacts

Tags: ios, cordova

```
function saveContact(contactObj) {
  var contact = navigator.contacts.create();
  var email = [1];
  //var len = contactObj.phone.length;
  var len = 2;
  var phoneNums = [len];
  email[0] = new ContactField("email",contactObj.email);
  contact.email = email;
  contact.nickname = contactObj.name;
  contact.givenName = contactObj.name;
  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    phoneNums[i] = new ContactField(contactObj.phone[i].type, contactObj.phone[i].number, contactObj.phone[i].pref);
  }
  contact.phoneNumbers = phoneNums;

  contact.save(onSaveSuccess, onSaveFail);
}
```

contactObj is an object that contains the name, email and a list of phone numbers.  The code hits onSaveSuccess and adds a contact with the correct name, but no phone numbers or emails are added.  Sample input (Stringified for transfer then parsed before being sent to the function)...

```
{"name":"Test User",
"email":"test@website.com",
"phone":{
  "0":{"type":"cell","number":"1231231234","pref":true},
  "1":{"type":"home","number":"1231231235","pref":false}}}
```

Anyone know why it isn't adding phonenumbers/emails?

EDIT: Turns out objects don't have a length... only arrays.  Email still isn't working though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the `contact.email` should actually be `contact.emails` and it also should be an array like `contact.phoneNumbers`.

Here's the exact structure :

```
{"type":"home","value":"xxxx@yyyy.zz","id":0,"pref":false}
```

Comment: You're absolutely right.  I really wish it didn't take me so long to find simple spelling mistakes /sigh.